LinkageError occurred while loading main class org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.JarLauncher
The following error occurs while trying to run the command
PS D:\Projekts\javaWebapp> spring --version      
Error: LinkageError occurred while loading main class org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.JarLauncher
        java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/springframework/boot/loader/launch/JarLauncher has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 55.0

And I am aware of the  Java Version Numbers where, 61 = Java 17 and I do have openjdk 17 installed still error is occuring
PS D:\Projekts\javaWebapp> java --version
openjdk 17.0.8.1 2023-08-24
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-17.0.8.1+1 (build 17.0.8.1+1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-17.0.8.1+1 (build 17.0.8.1+1, mixed mode, sharing)


What exactly is the spring executable you showed in your first snippet? Is it a script file or a third party product? Do you build it somehow with your build process and if yes, how?

sorry for not clarifying spring is framework to make webapps in JAVA for more info you can visit https://spring.io/projects/spring-framework

I know of Spring framework, but after a bit of research it seems that you are using Spring Boot CLI - which is not part of the Spring framework, but of Spring boot. You should mention this is your question.

Did you check the contents of your JAVA_HOME environment variable? It is not directly tied to the path to java.exe but a script like the Spring Boot CLI could depend on it to find the correct version of Java to use.

try to see if your system has installed OpenJDK 17 more than once so it is taking that one. try to reinstall and uninstall all other OpenJDK then add environment variables and try.

Make sure it's picking up the correct Java version. You can specify the full path to the Java binary to avoid any ambiguity:
"path\to\your\java17\installation\bin\java" -version

Use the same full path when running your Spring command if necessary.

Can you check the following environment variables? spring command might take one of them taking an older JDK/JRE-Version:
Windows (Cmd, not Powershell):
set JDK_HOME
set JRE_HOME
set JAVA_HOME

Linux:
echo $JDK_HOME
echo $JRE_HOME
echo $JAVA_HOME

If this is the case, adapt your environment variable to the one given in your path:
Windows:
set PATH

Linux:
echo $PATH

Use the directory listed there for your JDK/JRE to set the environment variable for the variable that is overridden, here e.g. for JAVA_HOME before executing spring:
Windows (respectively your directory of choice):
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Programs\JDK17 

Linux (respectively your directory of choice):
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java17-openjdk

You also can set the environment variable permanently using this method in Windows or adding the export statement above to your .bashrc in Linux.

Can you confirm is JAVA_HOME env variable is setup correctly? If not, add it.
also try telling maven to pick source and target versions of java, this way:
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>17</source>
                <target>17</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

